# Pegar dados de uma tabela HTML dinâmica

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela dinâmica em HTML do qual traz o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As colunas **Português** e **Matemática**, vem do banco de dados e são dinâmicas, ou seja, podem conter mais matérias. O mesmo ocorre com a coluna **Alunos**, que também é dinâmica e vem do banco de dados.

Observem que as notas de Fernando Pessoa são: Português 11 e Matemática 12 e de Santos Dumont é Português 13 e Matemática 14.

Para gerar essa tabela, fiz da seguinte forma. (corrijam-me se eu estiver feito errado):

```
public function materiasNotas($idEscolas,$idTurmas){
.....
$listar = "<table class=\"table table-bordered\">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                   <th style='background-color: #4682B4; color: #FFF; text-align: center'>Alunos</th>";
       while($jmListar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlListar)){  
             $listar .= "<th style='background-color: #4682B4; color: #FFF; text-align: center'>".$jmListar->Materias."</th>";
        }    
             $listar .= "<th style='background-color: #4682B4; color: #FFF; text-align: center'>Boletim</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>";

       $sqlAlunos = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM pe_cadastros_alunos WHERE IdEscolas = '".$idEscolas."' AND IdTurmas = '".$idTurmas."';");

       while($jmAlunos = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlAlunos)){
             $listar .= "<tbody>";
             $listar .= "<td style='background-color: #B0C4DE'><input type='text' name='Alunos[]' value='".$jmAlunos->NomeCompleto."' style='border: 0; background-color: #B0C4DE;' readonly></td>";
             //$i = 1;
             $sqlMat = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM pe_materias WHERE IdEscolas = '".$idEscolas."' AND IdSeries = '".$jmTurmas->Series."';");
             while($jmMat = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlMat)){                   
                 $listar .= "<td><div align='center'><input type='hidden' name='Materias[]' value='".$jmMat->Materias."'><input type='text' name='Notas[]' placeholder='Nota' style='width: 100px'></div></td>";                
             } 
             $listar .= "<td><div align='center'><button class='btn btn-success btn-xs'><i class=\"fa fa-print fa-lg\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> Imprimir</button> <button class='btn btn-success btn-xs'><i class=\"fa fa-envelope fa-lg\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> E-mail</button> <button class='btn btn-success btn-xs'><i class=\"fa fa-download fa-lg\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> Baixar</button></div></td>";
             $listar .= "</tbody>";
        }  
         $listar .= "</table>";
         return $listar;    
}
```

O problema está na hora de cadastrar no banco de dados, pois ele está me retornando dessa forma:

Observem que os nomes não estão batendo com as notas citadas acima, ou seja, na segunda linha era pra ficar o Fernando Pessoa e Santos Dumont era para ficar na terceira e quarta linhas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou cadastrando dessa forma:

```
public function cadastrarNotasAlunos($idEscola,$aluno,$bimestre,$materias,$notas,$situacao){
 ....    
    for($i = 0; $i <= count($notas) - 1; $i++){
            mysqli_query($this->conexao, "INSERT INTO pe_notas_alunos VALUES(null,'".$idEscola."','".$aluno[$i]."','".$materias[$i]."','".$notas[$i]."','".   $bimestre."','".$situacao."');");
    }    
}
```

Como eu faria para que os nomes fossem cadastrados conforme suas notas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo acredito que na sua função de cadastrar o aluno não é uma matriz e sim um constante. Não sendo necessário incrementa no caso de vir mais de uma nota.

```
mysqli_query($this->conexao, "INSERT INTO pe_notas_alunos VALUES(null,'".$idEscola."','".$aluno."','".$materias[$i]."','".$notas[$i]."','".   $bimestre."','".$situacao."');");
```

php não é meu forte, a solução ideal ai seria a criação do objeto pe_notas_alunos e seria enviado uma matriz de pe_notas_alunos.

porem acredito que esse codigo abaixo deva funcionar

```
for($a = 0; $a <= count($aluno) - 1; $a++){  
    for($i = a*(count($notas)/count($aluno)) $i <= (count($notas)/count($aluno)) + a*(count($notas)/count($aluno)) - 1; $i++){
          mysqli_query($this->conexao, "INSERT INTO pe_notas_alunos VALUES(null,'".$idEscola."','".$aluno[$a]."','".$materias[$i]."','".$notas[$i]."','".   $bimestre."','".$situacao."');");
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Felipe. Na verdade o aluno é uma matriz name='Alunos[]'

Comment: O problema esta exatamente ai quando você passa a matriz de aluno com 2 elementos e a de notas com 4 elementos e faz a iteração com a mesma variável.

Comment: Entendi.... você poderia me dar um exemplo? Pois realmente não sei o que fazer...

Comment: Olá Felipe. Vou tentar com seu código...